# A program that calculates how dense each character appears when printed

Tags: python, python-3.x, ascii-art

I wanted to know how "dark" each character is when printed. I thought that this may be useful when doing ASCII-art to help with shading. I decided to write a program to objectively measure how much coverage of an area each character provides, which should roughly translate to how dark it appears when printed and zoomed out from.

First, here are the results for pt. 100, FreeSans font, for all visible ASCII characters:

```py
>>> pairs = find_half_coverage_for_printable()
>>> pairs.sort(key=lambda p: p[1], reverse=True)
>>> pairs

[('@', 0.3015),
 ('W', 0.2499),
 ('M', 0.241),
 ('B', 0.2052),
 ('Q', 0.1996),
 ('G', 0.1962),
 ('N', 0.1931),
 ('R', 0.189),
 ('O', 0.1816),
 ('D', 0.1795),
 ('$', 0.1782),
 ('S', 0.1723),
 ('&', 0.171),
 ('%', 0.1677),
 ('E', 0.1658),
 ('8', 0.1653),
 ('g', 0.1653),
 ('m', 0.1624),
 ('H', 0.162),
 ('w', 0.1597),
 ('A', 0.1594),
 ('#', 0.1578),
 ('K', 0.1573),
 ('9', 0.1571),
 ('6', 0.1569),
 ('C', 0.1539),
 ('U', 0.153),
 ('Z', 0.153),
 ('P', 0.1513),
 ('X', 0.1501),
 ('d', 0.1482),
 ('q', 0.148),
 ('b', 0.1477),
 ('p', 0.1472),
 ('5', 0.1453),
 ('0', 0.1434),
 ('2', 0.1414),
 ('3', 0.1384),
 ('V', 0.1324),
 ('a', 0.1316),
 ('e', 0.131),
 ('4', 0.1277),
 ('F', 0.1259),
 ('h', 0.1228),
 ('o', 0.1177),
 ('k', 0.1171),
 ('Y', 0.1152),
 ('s', 0.1139),
 ('y', 0.1089),
 ('u', 0.1061),
 ('n', 0.1059),
 ('T', 0.1042),
 ('c', 0.1002),
 ('J', 0.0997),
 ('[', 0.0967),
 (']', 0.0967),
 ('z', 0.0962),
 ('7', 0.0947),
 ('L', 0.0945),
 ('?', 0.0903),
 ('x', 0.09),
 ('v', 0.0869),
 ('{', 0.0826),
 ('}', 0.0772),
 ('1', 0.0764),
 ('f', 0.0727),
 ('>', 0.0711),
 ('j', 0.0708),
 ('<', 0.0708),
 ('t', 0.0705),
 ('(', 0.0672),
 (')', 0.0672),
 ('=', 0.0672),
 ('I', 0.0657),
 ('|', 0.0649),
 ('+', 0.0624),
 ('l', 0.0584),
 ('r', 0.0572),
 ('!', 0.0528),
 ('i', 0.0504),
 ('^', 0.0499),
 ('/', 0.0411),
 ('\\', 0.041),
 ('"', 0.0382),
 ('*', 0.0379),
 ('~', 0.0342),
 (';', 0.03),
 ('_', 0.0289),
 ("'", 0.0202),
 (':', 0.02),
 (',', 0.0177),
 ('-', 0.0168),
 ('`', 0.0125),
 ('.', 0.01)]
```

Or, with just the characters, it's clearly somewhat accurate:

```c
@WMBQGNROD$S&%E8gmHwA#K96CUZPXdqbp5023Vae4FhokYsyunTcJ[]z7L?xv{}1f>j<t()=I|+lr!i^/\\"*~;_\':,-`.
```

So by this measure, `@` is the "darkest" character, and `.` is the "lightest" (which makes intuitive sense; although I expected `#` to rank higher).

The program works by using [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to draw a (by default) 100 pt. character onto a 100x100 image in memory, then it manually checks each pixel of the image. If the color satisfies a predicate, that pixel is considered to be "covered". It then calculates the percentage coverage and returns it. By default, the predicate is a check to see if the sum of the three channels exceeds `(255 + 255 + 255) // 2`. This can be easily changed though by supplying a custom predicate.

As I note in the docstring though, this method does not produce absolute coverage measures, since the images are a little bigger than the drawn characters. The 30.15% coverage of `@` is including a lot of whitespace, and would be higher if corrected. Unfortunately, trying to get images exactly as large as the character creates its own problems, and relative coverages are fine anyways. There's also a minor issue that some characters, depending on the font, can hang down *slightly* outside of the image. I'm offsetting to the left by 5 pixels to account for that, but there's still issues of "overflows" near the bottom. It doesn't seem to serious though, so I left it. Underscores will be impacted the most by it.

I know I'm not doing everything as efficiently as I could be (like only using 1 process, and accessing pixels in a naïve way). It's surprisingly fast though, so optimizations didn't seem necessary. I'd be interested though in any improvements people can see though, as I don't do image manipulation very often.

```
from typing import Tuple, Callable, Iterable, List
import string as sg

from PIL import Image as ig
from PIL.Image import Image
import PIL.ImageFont as ft
import PIL.ImageDraw as dw

Color = Tuple[int, int, int]
ColorPredicate = Callable[[Color], bool]

_DEFAULT_FONT = "FreeSans"
_DEFAULT_TEST_SIZE = 100  # The size of the image and the font
_DEFAULT_CHAR_SET = sg.digits + sg.ascii_letters + sg.punctuation
_DEFAULT_IMG_SIZE_MULT = 1.10
_DEFAULT_CHAR_COLOR = (0, 0, 0)

_DRAW_OFFSET = (5, 0)

_COLOR_TUP_MAX_SUM = sum((255, 255, 255))


def _new_image(width: int, height: int) -> Image:
    return ig.new("RGB", (width, height), (255, 255, 255))


def _draw_character(image: Image, char: str, font: ft.ImageFont, color: Color = _DEFAULT_CHAR_COLOR) -> None:
    draw = dw.ImageDraw(image)
    draw.text(_DRAW_OFFSET, char, color, font)


def _count_selected(image: Image, pred: ColorPredicate) -> int:
    pix = image.load()

    count = 0
    for y in range(image.height):
        for x in range(image.width):
            if pred(pix[x, y]):
                count += 1

    return count


def find_percent_coverage(char: str,
                          pred: ColorPredicate,
                          image_width: int,
                          font: ft.ImageFont) -> float:

    img = _new_image(image_width, image_width)
    _draw_character(img, char, font)

    count = _count_selected(img, pred)

    return count / (image_width * image_width)


def half_color_predicate(color: Color) -> bool:
    return sum(color) <= (_COLOR_TUP_MAX_SUM >> 1)


def find_coverage_for(chars: Iterable[str],
                      pred: ColorPredicate,
                      image_width: int = _DEFAULT_TEST_SIZE,
                      font_name: str = _DEFAULT_FONT,
                      ) -> List[Tuple[str, float]]:
    """
    Counts the number of pixels each character covers in an image, and return each result as a tuple of
      (character, percent_coverage).

    Unless the character is exactly as large as the image, the returned coverage percentages will not be absolute. They
      only have meaning relative to other results.
    """

    font = ft.truetype(font_name, image_width)

    return [(c, find_percent_coverage(c, pred, image_width, font)) for c in chars]


def find_half_coverage_for_printable(image_width: int = _DEFAULT_TEST_SIZE,
                                     font_name: str = _DEFAULT_FONT
                                     ) -> List[Tuple[str, float]]:

    return find_coverage_for(_DEFAULT_CHAR_SET, half_color_predicate, image_width, font_name)
```

Comment: Interesting problem...

Comment: Rather than use a fixed 100x100 image, ImageFont has a [method](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageFont.html#methods) `getsize(text)` that returns the width and height of `text` in pixels.

Comment: @RootTwo Yes. I didn't verify the math, but I worried that differently sized images would lead to percentages that would be harder to compare.

Comment: @Carcigenicate. I guess it depends on the font.  For a fixed width font, the calculations could be off by a constant factor.  For a proportional font it might make a bigger difference.  A string like '|||||||' would have a lot higher density in a proportional font.

Comment: @RootTwo Ya, I realized how much of a factor the spacing of font plays when I did some tests. I had the program print out giant blocks of text to file, in the order of characters at the start of the question. There's a *general* tendency towards lighter characters at the end, but there's spikes of dark where certain characters fit together closer. I really need to use a mono spaced font for this, which I don't think OpenSans is.

Comment: If you want to learn how to do this correctly, you either need to use a mono spaced font, or learn about kerning. Either way, you want the final ascii art to match (which probably means mono)

Answer (score 3):

I like the overall concept you're pursuing.

---

Yay, kudos for optional type hinting!

Your goal was to better communicate
details to human collaborators,
and you succeeded.

---

I feel this is a code defect:

```
_DEFAULT_FONT = "FreeSans"
```

Why?
Because the code assumes characters
(and character **widths**)
are comparable to one another.
But this is a proportionally spaced font.

Please specify a mono font.

---

You have some 2-letter imports, such as

```
from PIL import Image as ig
```

Ok, sure, I get where your head's at.
It's not completely opaque.
But consider adopting more pronounceable
aliases like `img`, `fnt`, `drw`.
(Though I will concede that
a type hint like `font: ft.ImageFont`
is *perfectly* legible and quite concise.
And `dw.ImageDraw` also works well.
So maybe I'm just crabby about `ig.new()`.)

---

In `_new_image` we setup an RGB canvas.

Here's a global strategy critique: why three channels?

Better to use grey scale from the get go, no?
Since the ASCII output is single channel.

---

I am reading `_count_selected`.

Python is a nice language, but
the cPython bytecode is a trifle slow on loops.
Here, `x` is the inner loop.
If we could possibly turn that into
a numpy [sum()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html)
call, that would be winning.
The initial conversion could be as simple as `np.array(pix)`.

Run [cProfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html#module-cProfile)
before & after such a refactor, to verify.

---

Everything about `find_percent_coverage`
is extremely clear, good job.

But `half_color_predicate` seems needlessly obscure.
Rather than `>> 1`, prefer `// 2`.
It's not like we're trying to help a compiler
generate efficient native instructions,
and besides any JIT attempts would surely
pick up on a constant divisor.
Do we wish to clearly communicate our intent
to the machine? No,
[that's secondary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_and_Interpretation_of_Computer_Programs).
Communicating to humans is always the primary concern.

---

The "relative darkness" approach makes perfect sense.
You produced a nice rank-ordered listing.

But ultimately a monospaced output function is going to need
absolute figures so it can choose appropriate characters.
Next step for developing this module would be a function
that accepts lines of text and outputs a "large" image.

With that in hand, I recommend you call *that* function
during darkness calibration. Simply send it the same
character repeated many times, for many lines.
This will let you gauge how much lightness the inter-character
and inter-line spacings are introducing.

As a separate matter, you voiced some concerns about
characters moving around within the grid, e.g. descenders.
It's easy to find single-character bounding boxes,
just look for zero rows and columns.
For any given mono font at 100 pt,
you might want to compute max bbox,
as yet another aid to estimating density and
to understanding how small those spacings can be squished.

It could also help with pruning "troublesome"
characters, such as `_` underscore, which
impair your ability to tighten up the spacings.

---

Overall, I find the code offers admirable clarity.

Comment: Thank you. I'll keep this stuff in mind if I ever revisit the project.

Answer (score 2):

I have nothing to add about the code itself. But I wanted to give some pointers wrt image processing.

Instead of counting pixels above some threshold, you should sum the pixel intensities. When rendering a font, two things happen that cause a bias in the thresholded count:

1. Anti-aliasing makes some pixels lighter to create the impression of smoother curves, finer details, and sub-pixel shifts. For example, a 1-pixel thick line could appear as a two-pixel thick line at half-intensity to simulate a line shifted by half a pixel. Both give a very similar darkness impression, but your code counts the second as either twice as dark or totally invisible depending on your chosen threshold. The sum of intensities is what anti-aliasing preserves, and therefore should also be what you compute.
2. When rendered in color, some systems will use the known configuration of the three colored components of each pixel to further refine the font shape. For example we can turn on the green component of one pixel and the red and blue of the neighboring pixel, to produce the effect of a white pixel shifted by 1/3 of a pixel. Again, using thresholds, you might not see this pixel as illuminated at all. Properly accounting for these colors requires understanding that we perceive green as much brighter than blue. So in the sum over pixel values, you need to take each color with the appropriate weight. Converting RGB to grayscale with the correct function from PIL should take care of this for you: `img = img.convert('L')`. But you might as well render to gray scale immediately.

Using NumPy you not only simplify your code, you also speed it up. Learning to use NumPy is strongly recommended when working with images. Your two lines

```py
count = _count_selected(img, pred)
return count / (image_width * image_width)
```

can be replaced by

```py
bin_img = np.sum(color, axis=2) <= (_COLOR_TUP_MAX_SUM // 2)
return np.mean(bin_img)
```

or simply

```py
return np.mean(img)
```

to incorporate my advice above.

Comment: Thank you. As with the other answer, I'll be sure to keep these tips in mind of I ever redo this project some something like it.